# Whats the propper way to use getters? (Trying to understand them)

Tags: properties

I have some little question related to getters:

After looking at the console, I saw I had lots of this errors:

```
KeyError: 'bpy_struct[key]: key (name of the key here) not found'
```

I saw that the error was only related to properties on which I defined setters/getters.

So, looking my set/get methods, they were like:

```
def get_element_name(self):
    return self["element_name"]

def set_element_name(self, value):
    self["element_name"] = value

value: StringProperty(default = "", set=set_element_name, get=get_element_name)
```

I **guess** that [the API says is like that](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#getter-setter-example) since I suppose that accesing the variables via the dict don't trigger the setter/getter (which would result in a loop between both methods).

First question: Is that the reason?

Second question: Is that really the propper/best way?

I mean, after some research, I saw in other person's code that their getters looked like:

```
def get_element_name(self):
    return self.get("element_name", "")
```

After changing to that in my code, my errors were gone. But since the Manual/API doesn't mention that way, I was wondering if that is a better way or not.

Also, I would like to ask what means that warning in the API:

```
Remember that these callbacks may be executed in threaded context.
```

I guess that it means that in someway, they are executed in a ""moment""/context were those variables may not be accessible in the thread, so thats why they launch an error.

So, that means that the last getter approach (with self.get(...)) is also not able to access the variable `element_name`, but since it has a default value set in the get(), Blender doesn't complain about it?

Also, I guess (again) that Blender doesnt complain about the setter since they are used in a ""safer context""? (I mean, I bet those errors of mine are UI related, trying to get the values while drawing (?))

TL;DR I wanted to know if the approach of using getter/setters (specially getters) in the API is correct.

Thank you so much.